# Finding child node's index

Tags: javascript

I have a parent div with some nested elements in it. They have the same class name without an id.
How can I get the value of a specific child node?

Comment: can you post an example html illustrating your problem ?

Comment: WHere's the code that you have so far?

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] first. After that come back to your question edit your question so it meets the guideline from Stack Overflow. If not, your question will be closed and you won't get any helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add id to your parent element, then

```
let parent = document.getElementById('parentid');
let chil = parent.children;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In a scenario where you want the value of a single specific elements, give it an id and refer to it using `document.getElementById(element's id)`.

If you're trying to get the value of every single nested element, you can use `document.querySelectorAll(elements' mutual class name)`. This gives you a list of nodes (basically an array) which you can iterate over and do whatever you need.

Comment: yup you are right this way worked too